# How to set different 404 error pages for different directory in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

Hi I have a website running on an domain lets say www.example.com. I also have a web application on the same website but in a directory lets say www.example.com/app/. Now the application also has different directory like www.example.com/app/a. I wanted to know how can I set different error 404 pages for the directories. For the first case I know I can do it using this:-

```
 error_page 404 /error404.html;
 location = /error404.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      internal;
 }
```

I wanted to know how can I set different pages for other directories. I would be highly grateful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1.Create 2 custom `404` pages named `err1.html` and `err2.html`

2.Change your config to something like the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /app {
        error_page 404 /err1.html;
    }
    location /loc {
        error_page 404 /err2.html;
    }
    location = /err1.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

when you browse to `/app` you will get `err1.html`, and `/loc` will give you `err2.html`